# A bounded sequence in $W^{1,1}((0,1))$ has no converging subsequence in $L^\infty ((0,1))$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, sequence-of-function

I am doing the exercise 8.2 from the brezis' book of Functional Analysis and PDEs, And I'm having trouble with the second question, which says:

> Construct a bounded sequence $(u_n)$ in $W^{1,1}((0,1))$ that admits
>   no sub-sequence con- verging in  $L^\infty ((0,1))$.

In the book he suggest to work with the following sequence:

$$u_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\ n(x-\frac{1}{2}), & \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq  \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \\ 1, & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \leq x  \leq 1 \end{cases}$$
This sequence is obviously in $W^{1,1}((0,1))$,  and it has no limits, but how can I proof that it can't has any converging sub-sequence in $L^\infty ((0,1))$? Any hint please?

Comment: $u_n(x)\to1$ for every $x$, so _if_ $u_{n_j}\to u$ in $L^\infty$ then $u=1$. But $||u_n-1||_\infty=1$ for  every $n$...

Comment: Um... $u_n(x)\to 1_{[1/2,1]}$, right? Your distance is still correct.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Oops.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I want just to say that the comvergence isn't for every $x$ Right?. Also I would like to know if I should keep the questino or it is better to delete it since it doesn't need any further answer?

Comment: Leave the question there. The worst that can happen is that someone stumbles upon it and learns something.

Comment: No, the convergence is for every $x$. Although  a correct version of the limit hasn't appeared yet. If $u=\chi_{(1/2,1)}$ then $u_n(x)\to u(x)$ for every $x\in(0,1)$. (This is clear if $x\le1/2$. If $x>1/2$ choose $N$ so $1/2+1/N<x$; then $u_n(x)=1=u(x)$ for  every $n>N$.))

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you for your further explanation